# Discrete logarithms: large prime modulus vs. large semi prime modulus

Tags: hash, modular-arithmetic

I have a cryptography homework question, in the question it says a cryptographic hash function in the form of $f(x) = g^x \bmod n$ ,  where $n$ is a very large prime (1024bits and more), $g$ is a generator for $\{1, 2, . . . , n − 1\}$, and $x$ is
possibly much more than 1024 bits in length. Comment on how well the function satisfies pre-image resistance and second pre-image resistance properties.

The second part of the question asks what would happen to the properties if $n$ is changed to $n = pq$ where $p$ and $q$ are very large primes (512 bits and more).

I know that the discrete log problem is very hard to solve for when $n$ is a very large prime, but what if $n$ is a large semi-prime number? Would the hash function still be pre-image and second-pre-image resistant?

Comment: If the attacker knows the factors of the modulus, they can compute the order. Given the order, finding collisions and second pre-images is trivial.

Comment: It's not true that the discrete log problem is hard whenever $n$ is a large prime; what other conditions on $n$ are necessary?  Also, why do you think that the function $g^x \bmod n$ for prime $n$ is second preimage resistant?

Comment: I think the question goes in the direction to show that if n is prime then the exponentiation is not second pre-image resistant, but if n is a product of two (unknown) primes, it is second preimage resistant.